# Issue using aiozmq.rpc with pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to do RPC using a Client Server model in PyQt5.

I've modified the client sample code for pyqt5, here is the original code (https://gist.github.com/martinku-tw/a35493bb40d3a91632a276492402a3ab) but I am running into an issue trying to use aiozmq.rpc with pyqt5.

When I try to get the return value from the rpc, I get an error 'TypeError: must be str, not coroutine'.

I am very new to rpc/socket programming and I am not sure if this the right way to do it in PyQt5.

Any help would greatly be appreciated,

I step through the code and looked at the ret object I do not see the return value. From what I could see, I don't think it's hitting the server code.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import asyncio
from aiozmq import rpc

app = QApplication([])
button = QPushButton('Click to myfunc1 results')

@asyncio.coroutine
async def run_client():
    print('start rpc client...')
    client = await rpc.connect_rpc(connect='tcp://127.0.0.1:5503')
    ret = await client.call.myfunc1(1, 13)

    return ret

def on_button_clicked():

    #ret = run_client().cr_code.co_consts[5]
    ret = run_client()

    alert = QMessageBox()
    alert.setText('myfunc1 results is: ' + str(ret))
    alert.exec_()

button.clicked.connect(on_button_clicked)
button.show()
app.exec_()
```

I am expecting a return string object from the server but getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aiozmq_client_qt_1.py", line 22, in on_button_clicked
    alert.setText('myfunc1 results is: ' + ret)
TypeError: must be str, not coroutine
[1]    6689 abort      python aiozmq_client_qt_1.py
```

Comment: What version of Python3 are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.6.